# Using template class inside another class

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a queue which will use generic item. I am receiving an error with the following code.

How to use the template class inside another class?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
class Item
{
public:
    Item(const T & item)
        : itemVal(item)
    {
    }

private:
    T itemVal;
};

class MyQueue
{
public:
    // Error #1
    void InsertNode(const Item & item); 

private:
    struct Node {
        // Error #2
        Item item; 

        struct Node * next;
    };
};

int main()
{
    Item<int> * element = new Item<int>(9);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: The error.  The line the error was created help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to redesign your class.

```
template<class T>
class MyQueue {

    struct Node {
        T item;
        Node * next;
    };

public:
    MyQueue();
    void InsertNode(const T & item);

private:
    Node * _root;
};
```

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Modified it as you have suggested.

Answer (score 2):

`Item` is not a type, it is a class template. You need to provide the template parameter. In this case, `int`:

```
void InsertNode(const Item<int> & item)
```

and

```
struct Node{
    Item<int> item;
    Node<int> * next;
};
```

Otherwise, you can make `MyQueue` and `Node` class templates.

Comment: Thanks. Making MyQueue and Node  as class templates solved the issue.